# 3 cards be selected from a pack of 52 playing cards if at least one of them is an ace? not more than one is an ace? Distributing 9 books to 3 peoples…

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently studying Extension 1 Mathematics. I missed two classes and I figured out that tomorrow I will have a quiz. Can you help me to solve this permutation and combination question:

> 1. In how many ways 3 cards be selected from a pack of 52 playing cards if:
>
>    **(i)** at least one of them is an ace;
>
>    **(ii)** not more than one is an ace.

> 2. In how many ways can 9 books be distributed amongst a man, a woman and a child, if the man receives $4,$ the woman $3,$ and the child $2$?

I know the solution (below), but **I don't understand how to get there**.

**$1$ (i)** $4804$ **(ii)** $21808$
**$2$** $1260$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it
1. (i) $3 * (51 * 50)$ and 
  (ii) $3 * (48 * 47)$ ?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Can you show your attempt?

Comment: @gaathiyo no, that's not it

Comment: what i had for 1(i) is actually 4* (51 C2), but I this yields 5100... not 4804

Comment: ooops.. @ZettaSuro please guide me

Comment: @gaathiyo are you familiar with binomial factors?

Comment: @ZettaSuro yes but how is it useful over here?

Comment: @gaathiyo check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** 1. (i) There are $\binom{52}{3}$ ways to draw $3$ cards. There are $\binom{48}{3}$ ways to draw $3$ cards without aces.

**Hint:** 1. (ii) There are $4$ aces and $\binom{48}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ cards without aces. Remember that no aces need be drawn.

**Hint:** 2. First think of the woman and child as one group and the man as another. How many ways are there to give $9$ books to them if the man gets $4$ and the group gets $5$? For each of those, how many ways can the $5$ books be given to the woman and child if the woman gets $3$ and the child gets $2$?

**Bonus:** Consider that $\binom{9}{5}\binom{5}{2}=\dfrac{9!}{4!\,3!\,2!}$ and how that relates to 2.

The answers in the book are correct.

Comment: thanks a ton! your hints are very clear!

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, consider the [rule of products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and the [rule of sums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum). To calculate the number of ways there can be at least one ace, you have to calculate how many ways there can be $1$ ace, $2$ aces, and $3$ aces, and add them together.

To calculate the number of $n$ card hands with $k$ aces, you must first consider that there are $4$ aces in a deck. The number of ways to draw $k$ of them is:

$$\binom{4}{k}$$

Then you must draw $n-k$ non-aces. There are $48$ non-aces, so the number of ways to draw $n-k$ of them is

$$\binom{48}{n-k}$$

Use the rule of products on these two factors to find the total number of $n$ card hands with $k$ aces.

Comment: okk, i'll try this in a few secs.

Comment: bt, the problem is why I could not "match" with the result (that I got from the answer key?)

Comment: @Joshua Can you show me the exact expression you used?

Comment: so, is it like this: first i need to check "only one ace" is required: 4C1 * 48C2 = 4512, next i need to evaluate for two aces which is 4C2 * 48C3 = 103776. Only adding these two, results more than 4804...

Comment: Your calculation for $1$ ace is correct, but with $2$ aces your expression is wrong. It appears you did $\binom{48}{n+k}$ instead of $\binom{48}{n-k}$.

Comment: ohh i see thanks @ZettaSuro

Comment: @Joshua You're welcome. Don't forget to select the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for 1(i):
$${52\choose 3}-{48\choose 3}\\
={4\choose 1}{48\choose 2}+{4\choose 2}{48\choose 1}+{4\choose 3}$$
Two ways for 1(ii):
$${48\choose 3}+{4\choose 1}{48\choose 2}\\={52\choose 3}-{48\choose 1}{4\choose 2}-{4\choose 3}$$
Six ways for 2:
$${9\choose 2}{7\choose 3}={9\choose 3}{6\choose 2}={9\choose 2}{7\choose 4}={9\choose 4}{5\choose 2}=...=...$$